# closed as duplicate - a non duplicate question

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question [How do I install Google Play on my stock android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/how-do-i-install-google-play-app-on-my-stock-android-device) was closed as an exact duplicate of [how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

These are different questions.  My question is a stock device without custom rom.  The answer for the suggested question does not work and is not applicable.  None of the linked information in the answers to that post work.  This answer, which I am providing to my own now closed question, does answer the question, and does not involve any custom firmware or rooting or flashing.

Kind regards.

The answer should be something like:

"Add Google Apps to your android device by following the information given by Google here - [Set up your Android for Google Apps](http://support.google.com/a/users/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1738362)

Pay special attention to their note about 2-step verification and [application specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833&topic=1056283&ctx=topic).  If you have 2 step verification turned on you need to generate a special one time password by visiting your Google accounts settings page, and then going to the Authorizing applications & sites page.

Comment: The question that you asked doesn't seem to have any relation to the answer you're proposing. Setting up an account is very different from installing Google's proprietary apps, and if Google's apps were not installed it would actually not even be possible to add a Google account through your settings as those instructions state. Were Google's apps preinstalled on your device or no?

Comment: The Google Play App ("white shopping bag") was not pre-installed.  It is installed when the account is set up.  (The other apps (mail etc) are pre-installed.)  Setting up the account includes a non-intuitive step for people with two-step verification.  Entering your normal password and email address will fail.  You need to enter your email and the specially generated one time password.  Doing that will set up your phone to use Google Apps; part of that set up is getting access to the Google Play app.  (And getting access to Google Play through a web browser on the phone).

Answer (score 3):

Just because a question is Closed doesn't mean that it is locked away forever. Being Closed gives the original author (and others) an opportunity to improve the question and, hopefully, get it re-opened.

If you believe that the questions are not essentially the same, then please edit your question to make that distinction. It would be a good idea to link to the other question and explain *why* yours isn't a duplicate.

If the community agrees, those with enough Reputation points can vote to re-open. If that process seems slow, you can Flag the question for a Moderator and explain that you've edited the question to make it clear it's not a duplicate. Or, you could raise the issue here (as you've done) but without making the edits to distinguish the questions it might not go very far.